# Как в Python, зашифровать или обезопасить свой код?

Tags: python-3.x

Написал я программу, а мне нужно, чтобы код не был прочитан, не подскажите, как делается обфускация на Python? Пытался с помощью pyinstaller, да, получалось шифровать код, но когда я перекидывал кому-либо эту программу она не запускалась

Comment: По сути никак. Любой код изначально на Python можно вытащить, в том числе и из экзешника, сформированного каким-нибудь PyInstaller. Можно просто не давать код пользователю - например писать сервис, а не десктопное приложение.